# Android O About ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices(int)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have one question.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices(int)

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.
>   As of O, this method is no longer available to third party applications. For backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services.

Does 'pre installed application' work the same as 'third party application'?

Answer (score 0):

Third party application in this context means 'an app not managed by Google'.

> Does 'pre installed application' work the same as 'third party application'?

Yes, unless the pre installed application is by Google.